# When a tag is merged, who gets the taxonomist badge when eligible?

Tags: support, tags, badges, tag-synonyms, taxonomist-badge

Who gets the "creation ownership" of a tag when they're merged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well generally when tags are merged, the tags with the least amount of questions are re-tagged to the same as the one with the most, so the person who created the more popular tag will be the one counted when it comes to that badge.

Comment: that would be my expectation too

Comment: Or speaking more generally,  the badge goes to the creator of the target of the merge.