# Why are we [merging] all of these concepts together?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, ambiguous-tags

The tag [merging](/questions/tagged/merging) has 47 questions and no excerpt or wiki. It seems to be used for the concept of merging things together, or when talking about merging things. However, we already have more specific tags for a lot of merge types!

- [merging questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343774/) ([merged-questions](/questions/tagged/merged-questions)... and [merge-questions](/questions/tagged/merge-questions))
- [merging tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121839/) part 1: how to ([merge-utility](/questions/tagged/merge-utility))
- [merging tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29912/) part 2: the aftermath ([tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms)?)
- [merging accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103689/) ([merge-accounts](/questions/tagged/merge-accounts))
- [merging sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348558/) ([site-merging](/questions/tagged/site-merging))
- [merging edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53412/) ([grace-period](/questions/tagged/grace-period)?)
- [merging proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58475/) (no other tag I could find)

Is it useful to have all of these kinds of merges merged into [merging](/questions/tagged/merging)? At the very least, the more specific tags could be added to the questions which lack them. The only use for [merging](/questions/tagged/merging) I can think of is as a catch-all tag, but even then it encourages people to use it instead of a more specific tag.

Comment: Related, since the tags are mentioned here: [Synonymize \[merged-questions\] and \[merge-questions\]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245253)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The specific tag topics all have their own challenges - user merges, and question merges for example are nothing alike. I'd prefer to go with looking at retagging the common 'merge' tag to specific ones.